# Pac-Man-ish maze game

Tags: java, beginner, homework, processing

I am a freshman in university. This Pac-Man-ish Game is my final Computer science homework. I know my code is not perfect and has so many to be improved. However, Compared to corrections of this game, I really appreciate to be given the hints or general principles that my code lack, which I could use in the future.

Here is what my professor wants:

> 1. Create a Maze.
> 2. Add prizes to each square.
> 3. Create a creature that the user can move through the maze with the arrows keys, consuming the prizes as it goes.
> 4. Create evil things that move through the maze and that the user must avoid.
> 5. At the beginning of each game, ask the user for its name
> 6. Keep track of the time the user takes to consume all of the prizes. The time will be the user’s score.
> 7. Keep a high scores list that displays at the end of each game. Just like with Asteroids, include a button to play again.
> 8. Write the high scores list to a file and read the high scores list from the file before it is displayed. That way the high scores will be
>      maintained when the application terminates.
> 9. Sort the high scores list before it is displayed using one of the sorting methods we discussed in class.

**`Square` class:**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Square {
    float xPos;
    float yPos;
    float widthOfSquare = 24;
    float heightOfSquare = 24;
    boolean blocked;
    boolean reached = false;
    boolean hasPrize = false;


    Square pred;


    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    Square(int xPos, int yPos, boolean blocked, int row, int col){
        this.xPos=xPos;
        this.yPos=yPos;
        this.blocked=blocked;
        this.row=row;
        this.col=col;
    }//end constructor

    void display(PApplet proc){

        if(blocked){
            proc.fill(0,0,255);
        }else {
            proc.fill(255,255,255);
        }




        proc.rect(xPos,yPos,widthOfSquare,heightOfSquare);

        if(hasPrize){
            proc.fill(0,255,0);
            proc.rect(xPos+widthOfSquare/3,yPos+heightOfSquare/3,8,8);
        }// end if







    }//end display;

    boolean setBlocked(boolean x){
        return blocked = x;
    }//end of setBlocked

    public boolean isBlocked(){
        return blocked;
    }//end isBlocked

    public void setReached(Boolean reached){
        this.reached = reached;
    }//end setReached

    public boolean isReached(){
        return reached;
    }//end isRe

    public int getCol(){
        return col;
    }//end getCol

    public int getRow(){
        return row;
    }//end getRow

    boolean hasPrize(boolean Prize){
        return hasPrize = Prize;
    }//end has Prize

    public Square getPred(){
        return pred;
    }//end getPred

    public void setPred(Square pred){
        this.pred = pred;
    }//end setPred

    public float getXPos(){
        return xPos;
    }//end getX

    public float getYPos(){
        return yPos;
    }//end getY





}//end Square class
```

**`Maze` class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Maze {

    Square[][] rect;
    ArrayList<Square> prizes = new ArrayList<Square>();


      int widthOfSquare = 24;
      int heightOfSquare = 24;
      int numCol;
      int numRow;
      double chanceOfBlocked;

      int currentCol = 0;
      int currentRow = 0;


      int evilsRow;
      int evilsCol;

      int evilsRow1;
      int evilsCol1;

      boolean gameEnd;
      boolean gameWin;




      public static final int LEFT = 1;
      public static final int RIGHT = 2;
      public static final int UP = 3;
      public static final int DOWN = 4;

      Maze(int numRow, int numCol, double chanceOfBlocked){
         this.numRow = numRow;
         this.numCol = numCol;
         this.chanceOfBlocked =chanceOfBlocked;

         setInit();




      }//end constructor

      void setInit(){
          widthOfSquare = 24;
          heightOfSquare = 24;
          numCol=30;
          numRow=10;


          currentCol = 0;
          currentRow = 0;


          evilsRow=0;
          evilsCol=0;

          evilsRow1=0;
          evilsCol1=0;

          gameEnd = false;
          gameWin = false;

          do{
              rect = new Square[numRow][numCol];
              for(int row= 0; row < numRow;row++){
                  for(int col = 0; col < numCol; col++){
                      double x = Math.random();

                      rect[row][col] = new Square(col*widthOfSquare, 
                                                  row*heightOfSquare,
                                                  (x<chanceOfBlocked),row,col);
                  }//end for
              }//end for 

              rect[0][0].setBlocked(false);
              rect[numRow -1][numCol-1].setBlocked(false);
              markReachable();


           }while( ! rect[numRow-1][numCol-1].isReached());

         for(int row= 0; row < numRow;row++){
             for(int col = 0; col < numCol; col++){
                 if(!rect[row][col].isReached()){
                     rect[row][col].setBlocked(true);
                 }//end if
             }//end for 
         }//end for

         for(int row= 0; row < numRow;row++){
             for(int col = 0; col < numCol; col++){
                 if(rect[row][col].isReached()){
                     rect[row][col].hasPrize(true);
                     prizes.add(rect[row][col]);
                     rect[0][0].hasPrize(false);
                 }//end if


             }//end for 
          }//end for

         do{ 
           evilsRow = (int)(Math.random() * numRow);
           evilsCol = (int)(Math.random() * numCol);
        }  while( !rect[evilsRow][evilsCol].isReached());

         do{ 
               evilsRow1 = (int)(Math.random() * numRow);
               evilsCol1 = (int)(Math.random() * numCol);
            }  while( !rect[evilsRow1][evilsCol1].isReached());
    }//end setInit


      void display(PApplet proc){
          for(int row= 0; row < numRow;row++){
              for(int col = 0; col < numCol; col++){

                  rect[row][col].display(proc); 

              }//end for 
          }//end for 
          proc.fill(255,0,0);
          proc.ellipse(currentCol*widthOfSquare+widthOfSquare/2,
                       currentRow*heightOfSquare+heightOfSquare/2,
                       10,10);




          proc.fill(0,0,0);
          proc.ellipse(evilsCol*widthOfSquare+widthOfSquare/2,
                  evilsRow*heightOfSquare+heightOfSquare/2,
                       10,10);

          proc.fill(0,0,0);
          proc.ellipse(evilsCol1*widthOfSquare+widthOfSquare/2,
                  evilsRow1*heightOfSquare+heightOfSquare/2,
                       10,10);
          drawPath(proc);


       }//end display

      void drawPath(PApplet proc){
          drawPath(proc, rect[numRow-1][numCol-1]);
      }//end drawPath

      void drawPath(PApplet proc, Square theEnd){
          Square thePred = theEnd.getPred();
          if(thePred !=null){
              proc.line(theEnd.getXPos()+widthOfSquare/2, theEnd.getYPos()+heightOfSquare/2,
                      thePred.getXPos()+widthOfSquare/2, thePred.getYPos()+heightOfSquare/2);
              drawPath(proc, thePred);
          }//end if


      }//end drawPath


      void move(int x){
          int newCol = currentCol;
          int newRow = currentRow;

          if(x == LEFT){
              newCol--;
          }else if(x == RIGHT){
              newCol++;
          }else if(x == UP){
              newRow--;
          }else if(x == DOWN){
              newRow++;
          }//end if


          if(newRow >= 0 && newRow < numRow && newCol >= 0 && newCol < numCol && !rect[newRow][newCol].isBlocked()){
              currentCol = newCol;
              currentRow = newRow;
          }//end if


          if(rect[currentRow][currentCol].hasPrize(true)){
                     rect[currentRow][currentCol].hasPrize(false);
                     prizes.remove(rect[currentRow][currentCol]);
                     prizes.remove(rect[0][0]);


          }//end if

          markReachable();
          moveEvil();


      }//end move

      void moveEvil(){
          if(rect[evilsRow][evilsCol].getPred() !=null){
              int newRow = rect[evilsRow][evilsCol].getPred().getRow();
              int newCol = rect[evilsRow][evilsCol].getPred().getCol();


               evilsRow = newRow;
               evilsCol = newCol;
          }//end if

          if(rect[evilsRow1][evilsCol1].getPred() !=null){
              int newRow = rect[evilsRow1][evilsCol1].getPred().getRow();
              int newCol = rect[evilsRow1][evilsCol1].getPred().getCol();


               evilsRow1 = newRow;
               evilsCol1 = newCol;
          }//end if
      }//end moveEvils

      void markReachable(){

          ArrayList<Square> openList = new ArrayList<Square>();
          for(int row=0;row<numRow;row++){
              for(int col = 0;col<numCol;col++){
                  rect[row][col].setReached(false);
                  rect[row][col].setPred(null);
              }//end for
          }//end for
          openList.add(rect[currentRow][currentCol]);
          rect[currentRow][currentCol].setReached(true);



          while(openList.size() > 0){


                  Square reachedRect = openList.remove(0);
                  int row  = reachedRect.getRow();
                  int col = reachedRect.getCol();



                  checkAndAddSquare(openList, row+1,col,reachedRect);
                  checkAndAddSquare(openList, row-1,col,reachedRect);
                  checkAndAddSquare(openList, row,col+1,reachedRect);
                  checkAndAddSquare(openList, row,col-1,reachedRect);
          }//end while
      }// end markReachable


      void checkAndAddSquare(ArrayList<Square> openList,int row,int col,Square currentSquare){
          if(row >= 0 && col >=0 && row < numRow && col < numCol 
                  &&! rect[row][col].isBlocked() && ! rect[row][col].isReached() ){
                  rect[row][col].setReached(true);
                  openList.add(rect[row][col]);
                  rect[row][col].setPred(currentSquare);
              }//end if
      }//end check




      void loseGame(){
          if(evilsRow == currentRow && evilsCol == currentCol
                   || evilsRow1 == currentRow && evilsCol1 == currentCol){
             gameEnd = true;
          }//end if
      }//end loseGame

      public boolean gameEnd(){
          return gameEnd;
      }//end if



      void winTheGame(){
          if(prizes.size()==0){     
               gameWin = true;
          }//end if          
      }//end winTheGame

      boolean gameWin(){
          return gameWin;
      }//end gameWin

      boolean setGameWin(boolean x){
        return gameWin= x;
      }//end of setBlocked







}//end Maze
```

**`Score` class:**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Score {
      String name;
      int score;


      Score(String n, int s){
          name = n;
          score = s;

      }//end constructor

      void display(PApplet proc){
          proc.text("name: score", 200,200);
      }//end display





      int getPoints(){
          return this.score;
      }//end getPoint

      public String toString(){
          return name+" "+score;
      }//end String


}//end class
```

**`MazeMain` class:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MazeMain extends PApplet{


    Maze theMaze;
    ArrayList<Character> name = new ArrayList<Character>();



    boolean doneEnteringName = false;
    boolean startAgain = false;
    boolean initGame = true;

    int start = frameCount;
    int elapsedTime = 0;
    double chanceOfBlocked = 0.25;

    PrintStream out;
    Score theScore;

    ArrayList<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>();


    public void settings(){
        size(1000,600);
    }//end settings

    public void setup(){
        theMaze = new Maze(10,30,chanceOfBlocked);
        theMaze.setInit();
        textSize(30);
        try{
            File inputFile = new File("score");
            Scanner scanFile =new Scanner(inputFile);

            while(scanFile.hasNextLine()){

                String line=scanFile.nextLine();
                Score theScore =readScore(line);



                scoreList.add(theScore);
            }//end while

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Bad file");
        }//end try-catch

    }//end setup

    public void draw(){
        background(127);
        if( theMaze.gameEnd()==false && theMaze.gameWin() == false){
            if(initGame){

                if(doneEnteringName){

                     theScore = new Score(getNameString(),0);               
                     theMaze = new Maze(10,30, chanceOfBlocked);
                     initGame =false;

                }else {

                    text("Maze Game!", 300,100);
                    text("enter your name   "+getNameString(), 250,300);

                }//end if

            }else {

                theMaze.display(this);
                text("Second =" +(int)((frameCount-start)/frameRate), 250,500);

                theMaze.winTheGame();
                theMaze.loseGame();

            }//end if

        }else if(theMaze.gameEnd){

             elapsedTime =(int)((frameCount-start)/frameRate);
             start = frameCount;
             fill(255,0,0);
             text("You Lose!", 360,125);
             fill(255,255,255);
             rect(350,350,200,60);
             fill(255,255,0);
             text("Start again?", 365,390);

             int heightOfScore = 100;
             for(Score Scores: scoreList){
                 text(Scores.toString(),100,heightOfScore);
                 heightOfScore += 50;
                }//end for

        }else if(theMaze.gameWin()){
            elapsedTime =(int)((frameCount-start)/frameRate);
            start = frameCount;
            fill(255,0,0);


            text("You Win! ", 360 ,125);
            fill(255,255,255);
            rect(350,350,200,60);
            fill(255,255,0);
            text("Start again?", 365,390);


            if(elapsedTime > 0){
                Score theScore = new Score(getNameString(),elapsedTime);
                this.scoreList.add(theScore);
            }//end if
             sort(scoreList,0);
             try{
                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream("score");
                    for(Score theScore: this.scoreList){
                        out.println(theScore);
                    }//end for
                    out.close();

                }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end try

            int heightOfScore = 100;
            for(Score Scores: scoreList){
                text(Scores.toString(),100,heightOfScore);
                heightOfScore += 50;
            }//end for
        }//end if

    }//end draw

    String getNameString(){
        String result = "";
        for(Character letter: name){
            result = result + letter;
        }//end for

        return result;
    }//end getNameString

    Score readScore(String line){
        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(line);
        String name = scanLine.next();

        int points = scanLine.nextInt();
        Score result = new Score(name,points);
        return result;
    }//end readScore()


    public void keyPressed(){
        if(key == CODED){
            if(keyCode == LEFT){
                theMaze.move(Maze.LEFT);
            }else if(keyCode == RIGHT){
                theMaze.move(Maze.RIGHT);
            }else if(keyCode == UP){
                theMaze.move(Maze.UP);
            }else if(keyCode == DOWN){
                theMaze.move(Maze.DOWN);
            }//end if
        }//end if

        if(!doneEnteringName){
            if(key !=CODED){
                if(key == ENTER){
                    doneEnteringName = true;
                }else if( key == BACKSPACE){
                    name.remove(name.size()-1);
                }else {
                    name.add(key);
                }//end if
            }//end if
        }//end if
     }//end keyPressed



    public void mousePressed(){
        if(mouseX>300 && mouseX<500 && mouseY>350 && mouseY<410){
            initGame = true;
            theMaze.gameEnd = false;
            theMaze.gameWin = false;
            doneEnteringName = false;
            start = frameCount;
        }//end if
    }//end mousePressed

    public static int findSmallestScore(ArrayList<Score> scoreList, int startIndex ){
        Score minSoFar = scoreList.get(startIndex);
        int minIndex = startIndex;

        for(int index=startIndex+1; index<scoreList.size();index++){
            if(minSoFar.getPoints() >scoreList.get(index).getPoints()){
                minSoFar = scoreList.get(index);
                minIndex = index;

            }//end if
        }//end for
        return minIndex;
    }//end sort

    public static void sort(ArrayList<Score> scoreList, int startIndex){
        if(startIndex < scoreList.size()){
            int minIndex = findSmallestScore(scoreList, startIndex);
            swap(scoreList, startIndex,minIndex);
            sort(scoreList,startIndex+1);
        }//end if
    }//end sort

    public static void swap(ArrayList<Score> scoreList, int first, int second){
        Score temp = scoreList.get(first);
        scoreList.set(first,scoreList.get(second));
        scoreList.set(second,temp);
    }//end swap


    public static void main(String[] agro){
        PApplet.main("MazeMain");
    }//end static
}//end MazeMain
```